# Crash on [NSURLConnection releaseDelegate] in a function without NSURLConnections, how do I culprit?

Tags: iphone, crash, ios-simulator, nsurlconnection

Hullo,
I am experimenting a very vicious crash that shows up in the following way in the device logs:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x50000008
Crashed Thread:  0`

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib               0x33b24c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                    0x3429465a _NSURLConnectionReleaseClient + 30
2   CFNetwork                     0x355ac608 ClientContextHolder<CFURLConnectionClient_V4>::forget() + 20
3   CFNetwork                     0x355ac5ea URLConnectionClient::releaseClientLocked() + 34
4   CFNetwork                     0x355a0e9a URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 170
5   CFNetwork                     0x355a0de2 URLConnection::multiplexerClientPerform(RunLoopMultiplexer*) + 30
6   CFNetwork                     0x355a0d54 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 120
7   CFNetwork                     0x355a0cd2 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 2
8   CoreFoundation                0x3039ca72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
9   CoreFoundation                0x3039e758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
10  CoreFoundation                0x3039f4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
11  CoreFoundation                0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
12  CoreFoundation                0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
13  GraphicsServices              0x35571418 GSEventRunModal + 108
14  GraphicsServices              0x355714c4 GSEventRun + 56
15  UIKit                         0x358c7d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
16  UIKit                         0x358c5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
17  inArrivo                      0x000023ca main (main.m:14)
18  inArrivo                      0x00002394 start + 32
```

After having enabled NSZombie I also have a crash on the compiler log of the following form:

> 2011-05-09 16:12:24.400 inArrivo[5019:707] *** -[NSURLConnection releaseDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d61670

appearing on the app main with the last NSLog comeing from a function with no url connections. Also if I remove some pieces of very innocent code from that function, no crash occurs, and the same happens when I run the complete application on the simulator.

Could someone give me some hints about what I may do to locate the piece of code producing the crash? Normal debugging of course is of little help here.

Thanks,
Fabrizio Bartolomucci

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that the delegate for NSURLConnection was deallocated. I would suggest you check the delegate object to see if you are doing an extra release on it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The problem was of course locating the culprit. What I did putting NSLogs everywhere upon a suggestion on the apple developer forum. Sure if it were possible to find the responsible simly from the crash log that would have made the issue much quicker to solve.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386177/sending-multiple-http-request-by-php/10386352), if Gary's answer was helpful, it would help Gary and everyone else who views this question in the future if you accept his answer.

Comment: As a matter of fact the crash occurred because of an array that was deleted and recreated by a thread while being accessed by another: I supposed using a flag would have prevented that effect but it was not evidently the case.